# iOS app never shows red popup on the notification tray

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, ios-app

I am running Stack Exchange iOS App Version 1.2.2 on iOS 8.1.2.

This morning I checked the iOS app and saw the following:

[image]

As you can see, there's no red popup with a number on the notification tray.  When I touched the notification tray, I saw the following:

[image]

That shows a comment from 36 minutes ago, which I had never seen before (since it had been longer than 36 minutes since I had previously checked SE).  So it should have showed a red popup with a "1" on the notification tray, but it didn't.  In fact, I have never seen a red popup on the notification tray in the iOS app.

Comment: [No repro](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qQKcW.png) in beta channel, version 1.2.2.196 so probably they already fixed the bug, and it would be available in app store when version 1.2.3 will be published.

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, I was also going to post a question about that +134 rep change.  That was wrong since it should have been just +10.  I suppose I should wait until 1.2.3 for that too?

Comment: Probably, yep. :)

Comment: @pacoverflow Do you have push notifications enabled?

Comment: @BrianNickel Notifications are turned off for the StackExchange app.  But still, that just means the iPhone won't alert me - I should still see be able to see red popups when launching the app, right?  Also, I do see the green popups for rep changes.

Comment: Yeah, something's breaking down there.  Originally the red indicator was 100% driven by the count passed in with push notifications.  Later it was reworked to update with web sockets while the app is running and (I didn't write it but I assume) do an initial check for unread messages at launch.  It's possible for example that the app never terminated and never requested new messages or that I just broke something. Will look into it.

Comment: @BrianNickel I just saw the red popup.  I was already in the iOS app for a few minutes though.  Still haven't seen a red popup after launching the app.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build.  If notifications are turned off the only thing driving the inbox count was realtime messages, which weren't sent if the app wasn't running.

I've changed things so that whenever the app becomes active it reloads the inbox data store and updates the unread count to the number of items where `isUnread == YES`.